# Reading huge amount of data throught i2c

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, arm, embedded-linux

I am trying to receive huge amount of data throught i2c. Here is my code. The main problem is that it takes more than 2 seconds when i need to let it be done in less than 0.5 sec. Here is the device: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lsm6ds33.pdf

[image with i2c interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFxk9.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define FIFO_DATA_OUT_L 0x3E
#define FIFO_DATA_OUT_H 0X3F

struct timeval stop, start;
int main()
{
    uint8_t addressL = FIFO_DATA_OUT_L;
    uint8_t addressH = FIFO_DATA_OUT_H;
    uint8_t resultL;
    uint8_t resultH;
    int16_t result;
    gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
    int fd;
    if ((fd = open("/dev/i2c-0",O_RDWR))< 0)
    {
        perror("failed to connect to i2c");
        exit(0);
    }
    ioctl(fd,I2C_SLAVE,0x6b);// Setting slave address
    long  i;
    for (i=0; i< 2499; i++)
    {
        write(fd,&addressL,1);
        read(fd,&resultL,1);
        write(fd,&addressH,1);
        read(fd,&resultH,1);
        result = (resultH << 8) | resultL;
    }
    gettimeofday(&stop,NULL);
    printf("Time elapsed: %d \n",stop.tv_sec-start.tv_sec);
    return;
}
```

I am wondering if there is some possibility to make things faster. Cheers.

Comment: Have you set 400kHz Fast Mode in your `/boot/config.txt`?

Comment: I doubt it will make much difference, but did you compile with `-O3 -march=native`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am not using raspberry so to change i2c speed i should compile whole kernel.

Comment: check i2c clock freq in your device tree, maybe SCL clock frequency is in standard mode.

Comment: are the addresses sequential? you can save overhead using a single read

Comment: you can switch to spi mode and sample much faster.

Comment: @old_timer Adresses remain same for whole process. When i read 2 bytes (LSb and MSb), device puts new values from buffer straight to adresses.

Comment: @AlbertoMerciai I've chanhged i2c clock freq to 400khz. It is better but still not fast enough.

Comment: Did you understand the question?  You can cut out at least 25% of the overhead.  26 instead of 36 clocks minimum plus less other overhead. or is it 28 vs 40?

Comment: how about writing/reading at the same time Low and High FIFO with a uint16_t instead of uint8_t? you must reduce you read/write call, so you can write/read once 
 reading 2 Byte then manipulate your data.

Comment: @old_timer 25% by switching to spi mode?

Comment: @AlbertoMerciai U mean writing to uint16_t two bytes?

Comment: @RafałDrozd i post my answer, let me know if it works ;)

Comment: sorry wrong number of clocks.   25% by doing one read instead of two.  but thinking about it it is one address, then one read, so 20,20,20,20 vs 20,26 (minimum) 80 clocks vs 46.  If you switch to spi mode you can go Mhz instead of Khz so as much as 25 times faster in spi, plus less overhead per transfer so that much faster as well so instead of 80 or 46 clocks per it is more like....25 clocks if these are 8 bit addresses?  so double that again 50 times faster max (reality would be less)

Comment: but there is also library overhead per transfer which is at chip clock speeds.

Comment: in theory though at 400Khz, perfect bus timing would be 0.5 seconds to do all of those transfers (at for transactions per), so that is theoretical perfection.  If possible to do it with 46 clocks then 0.29 seconds (so something slower than that).  with spi my guess would be 0.006 seconds theoretical, so something longer than that.

Comment: also understand that for some devices the more you pound on their interfaces the less well they perform, I didnt read the whole datasheet, just looked at bus specs.

Comment: And why you are not using the kernel driver for it?

Comment: @0andriy U mean my own kernel driver?

Comment: No. Already existing Linux kernel driver.

Comment: @0andriy could you explain it to me? I mean how to use it (e.g. example). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @0andriy do you mean including <i2c-dev.h>?

Comment: Here is the driver: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/imu/st_lsm6dsx Enable it in your kernel configuration and use via `libiio`. It will be **much** faster and productive.

Answer (score 0):

I think your FIFO size is 2 Byte then you can write/read 2 Byte each time instead of 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define FIFO_DATA_OUT_L 0x3E
#define FIFO_DATA_OUT_H 0X3F

struct timeval stop, start;
int main()
{
    uint8_t addressL = FIFO_DATA_OUT_L;
    uint8_t addressH = FIFO_DATA_OUT_H;
    uint16_t result;

    gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
    int fd;
    if ((fd = open("/dev/i2c-0",O_RDWR))< 0)
    {
        perror("failed to connect to i2c");
        exit(0);
    }
    ioctl(fd,I2C_SLAVE,0x6b);// Setting slave address
    long  i;
    for (i=0; i< 1250; i++)
    {
        write(fd,&addressL,2);
        read(fd,&result,2);
    }
    gettimeofday(&stop,NULL);
    printf("Time elapsed: %d \n",stop.tv_sec-start.tv_sec);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check that tomorrow and give feedback.

Comment: It's not as good as a proper way to communicate, i.e. using in-kernel driver.

Comment: @0andriy you're right, but a solution could be reducing the I/O op.  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface